# ViewBag missunderstanding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

How can I pass a float from controller to view using ViewBag?

this is my code in controller

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        float iva = Grupo_Macresa.Properties.Settings.Default.Iva;

        ViewBag.Iva = iva;
        return View();
    }
```

this is my view

```
@{
    float iva = ViewBag.Iva;
}
```

It comes null.

Comment: How have you tried to accomplish this?

Comment: Your code actually works on my computer without casting it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you retrieve things from the ViewBag, you need to cast them to the correct type.

So, in this case you need to do:

```
@{
    float iva = (float)ViewBag.Iva;
}
```

However, using ViewBag is not exactly best practice and you would be well advised to get into the habit of using ViewModels instead.

Some further reading: http://completedevelopment.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/stop-using-viewbag-in-most-places.html